# "On its behalf" idiom

Tags: idioms, legalese

I'm confused by the usage of the idiom "on its behalf" in this sentence:

> One of the key parts of the telecommunication is the action that one
>   device is asking another device to take **on its behalf**.

I think the meaning of that idiom is "instead of", but it seems pretty awkward to me there. Might there be other meanings which are more suitable there?

Comment: Could you explain, why you replace my "that" with your "the" in a sentence _I think the meaning of that idiom is "instead of"_. Does it make no sense there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On its behalf = for it.

Device A asks|tells device B to do something.  B does it on A's behalf.  B does it for A.

**Would you go to the town council for me and tell them they're a bunch of idiots?**

```
Kiril: Dmitry, why are you here before the town council today? 
Dmitry: I am here on behalf of Tim, who asked me to say you were a bunch of idiots.
```